# Sending object from android to PC through socket... how to import the package?

Tags: java, object, package, file-transfer

I want to send an object that contains file, file name, file size, etc. I created a serializable class called `Data` in android studio. Android Studio writes an object `Data data = new Data(file, filename, filesize)`, but I cannot receive it on another project on PC because server project requires the class `Data` from Android Studio. Also, my server project is on my VM.

My question is how do I `import com.example.client_example.Data` class in my **server project**?

Comment: One way to solve this is creating a third project that is a pure library. Then you add this library as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Joni, creating a library and adding it to both projects worked. One thing to note: since I was using different JRE (Netbeans only support up to SE8 and Android Studio is using SE14 I believe), library had to be in Java SE8. When I first made it in SE14, it did not work on NetBeans.

Note: Yes I could use Apache NetBeans, but I had a technical issue installing it and was too lazy to solve that.